# Policy setting 'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff' - Enabled

Tags: search

Today, we have encountered the issue with the SharePoint 2010 search, have verified and found that it is an known issue with Windows server 2008(R2).

many articles says that we have to enable the policy setting 'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff' on the server where the search service is running on.

Is it fine to do so?

**Note:**
IIS reset have fixed the issue.

**Reference articles:**
•   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/b464d58a-32ff-44d0-93dd-b7b240e96869 
•   http://www.mysticslayer.com/?p=200
•   http://pacsharepoint.com/2011/11/sharepoint-search-illegal-operation.html
•   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/06/a-com-server-application-may-stop-working-on-windows-server-2008.aspx
•   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947238

**ULS Logs:**

> 02/01/2012 09:06:52.84  w3wp.exe (0x1018)        0x1E28  SharePoint
>   Server Search             Query   dka5      High
>   SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for
>   deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal
>   to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation
>   attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)     at System.Se...).
>   ad5d91ce-6900-4436-b994-6a2dc54c23ce
>
> 02/01/2012 09:06:52.84  w3wp.exe (0x1018)        0x1E28  SharePoint
>   Server Search             Query   dlr1        High       Exception
>   when fetching results:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for
>   deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal
>   to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation
>   attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)     at System.Se...).
>   ad5d91ce-6900-4436-b994-6a2dc54c23ce
>
> 02/01/2012 09:06:52.85  w3wp.exe (0x1018)        0x1E28  SharePoint
>   Server Search             Query   g1j9        Exception
>   Internal server error exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for
>   deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal
>   to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation
>   attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.KeywordQueryInternal.Execute()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.QueryInternal.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at SyncInvokeExecute(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)     at System.Se...).
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for
>   deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA) (Fault Detail is equal
>   to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Illegal operation
>   attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)     at
>
> 02/01/2012 09:06:52.85  w3wp.exe (0x1018)        0x1E28  SharePoint
>   Server           General                7888       Warning
>   A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Thread was
>   being aborted.  Technical Details:
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()     at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)     at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.End()     at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String
>   message, String linkText, String linkUrl)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.QueryUIError.GetErrorMessageOrRedirectToErrorPage(Exception
>   ex, Boolean showMessages)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsDatasourceView.GetXmlResponseDoc(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   selectArguments)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String
>   viewPath)           ad5d91ce-6900-4436-b994-6a2dc54c23ce
>
> **Event viewer logs:**
>  Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be
>   unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry
>   file may not function properly afterwards. DETAIL - 4 user registry
>   handles leaked from
>   \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1593251271-2640304127-1825641215-1112252_Classes:
>   Process 8968
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1593251271-2640304127-1825641215-1112252_CLASSES
>   Process 7156
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1593251271-2640304127-1825641215-1112252_CLASSES
>   Process 8968
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1593251271-2640304127-1825641215-1112252_CLASSES
>   Process 7156
>   (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe) has opened
>   key
>   \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-21-1593251271-2640304127-1825641215-1112252_CLASSES
>   0              1530       2012-01-31 10:45:00
>   Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles Service

Comment: none has clue? any suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before and setting that policy setting never solved our problem. We were able to configure the search, add sources, crawl, define managed properties,... but firing queries gave us the exact error as mentioned above.

We only solved it the drastic way. Remove the search application and reconfigure it from scratch. I reckon, in our case, some bad permissions / settings were to blame.